# year-over-year percentage change in R

Tags: r, time-series

though I have found several similar questions, I could not find a simple solution to my problem in base R.
I want to calculate the yoy percentage change from a set of data (here the y value) and add this "Delta"-series as a new column to my data frame.

For example:

```
>x = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006)   
>y = c(100,104,106,108,112,115,121)   
>df = data.frame(x,y)
```

And what to do if I load my data by reading a .csv file? Do i have to convert this data to a data frame?

Comment: By using `read.csv/read.table`, you are directly getting a `data.frame`.  No need for any conversion.  What is the expected output based on your `df`?

Comment: Are you looking for `y[-1]/y[-7]`? Or more general `df$y[-1]/df$y[-nrow(df)]`

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for those answers. I was looking for something like `df$y[-1]/df$y[-nrow(df)]`
But if I do `transform df = (df, new.col = c(NA, df$y[-1]/df$y[-nrow(df)]-1))`
I get an error message: `Error: unexpected symbol in "transform df"`

Comment: You transform needs to change `transform(df, new.col=c(NA, df$y[-1]/df$y[-nrow(df)]-1))`

Comment: Apparently I do not have the package "data.table"

Comment: You can install the package, but what is wrong in using the `transform` from base R

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for those very fast answers! I used the transform answer! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[data.table_1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) introduced new function `shift`, which by default will be `type='lag'` and `n=1L`.  You could specify those arguments, if you need to change.  `setDT` converts `data.frame` to `data.table`, a new column is created (`:=`) based on the criteria (`y/shift(y)...`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, new.col := y/shift(y) - 1]
```

Or in base R (from @David Arenburg's comments)

```
transform(df, new.col=c(NA,y[-1]/y[-nrow(df)]-1))
```